# How to create mesh renders from a 2D image

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, 3dsmax

I have a 2D image of a mans face that I want to hook up to Rogo Digital's LipSync Unity plug-in.  I am not a 2D or 3D modeler so I don't know what I don't know.  If I were to post a project on a website to ask for someone to convert my 2D image into something that I can hook up to the LipSync plugin what do I need to ask for?

Comment: You need to create a 3d mesh then UV map the vertices according to what part of the texture belongs at that vertex.  You'll also need to doctor the photo so that it wraps onto the mesh properly. [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63246/how-do-i-make-a-3-dimensional-character-out-of-flat-picture) can help you get started. It's specifically for Blender users but it applies more generally, as well.

Comment: Is there no way to do the mesh in 2D?  I don't really need the 3D model like in the example you sent.

Comment: The above method works for meshes from 0D to 3D. You can keep as many dimensions set to 0 as you'd like. If you really want to manually set all the vertex placement and UV mapping as an exercise, you can do so  [procedurally](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GeneratingMeshGeometryProcedurally.html). But there's no practical reason to do that if all you want is a mesh of a specific face.

Comment: Ok, what your saying is all greek to me :)  I want to post this project to a site to have someone do this for me as I don't really want to learn how to do it.  I need to know how to ask someone else to do it.  What would a sample post look like?

Comment: You'll want them to **model** and **texture** the face in the photo. I don't think you'll need **rigging** - the plugin looks like it will handle that for you.

Comment: The plugin uses mesh blends to hook up the phenomes to animate the lip synchs. Do I need to mention that when asking for them to model and texture the photo or is a mesh blend implicit?  More specifically, the mesh blends have to mimic the phonomes.  The mouth is in the shape of an O for the O phenome, the mouth is closed with lips pursed for M phenome, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183913/discussion-between-ruzihm-and-slaphshot33324).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a 3d model with 2d image, you need photoscan or other of the same genre.
[3d scan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ul9aYhm7O4)